# How to install GUI on ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: server

I am new to ubuntu server. I want some GUI features in ubuntu server.Is it possible to  install GUI on ubuntu server.If yes then please help me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**If you want to administer locally**

You can install the default Ubuntu desktop by executing the following:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

There are many desktop alternatives which you may install and use, like:

- [Gnome 3](http://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/) installation: `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`
- [KDE](http://www.kde.org/) see [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) installation: `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`
- [XFCE](http://www.xfce.org/) installation: `sudo apt-get install xfce4`
- [LXDE](http://lxde.org/) installation: `sudo apt-get install lxde`
- [Openbox](http://openbox.org/) installation: `sudo apt-get install openbox`
- Gnome Classic (**old**) a Gnome 3 desktop that looks like Gnome 2 installation: `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`
- [Ubuntu Gnome](https://ubuntugnome.org/) (Official flavor) installation: `sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

**Local and or remote administration**

Except from the above you can administer your server by using a web based solution using less resources:

- [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) installation: [see here](http://www.webmin.com/deb.html)
- [Zentyal](http://www.zentyal.com/) (offers community edition) installation: [see here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/zentyal.html)
- [ISPConfig](https://www.ispconfig.org/) (supports up to 16.10) installation: [see here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-ubuntu-16.04-with-apache-php-myqsl-pureftpd-bind-postfix-doveot-and-ispconfig/)

Comment: Follow up question: once installation is complete and machine is restarted, will the GUI run automatically after startup? If not: (a) how to start it? (b) how to set it to start automatically on future restarts? Any help appreciated. Thanks.